# Showing all object output in the console VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `console.log(object)` to print an object in JavaScript (Nodejs) using the VS code terminal.

```js
object = { data: 1, next: { data: 2, next: { data: 3, next: { data:  4, next:  null }}}}; 
console.log(object)
```

The terminal shows:

```js
>>> { data: 1, next: { data: 2, next: { data: 3, next: [Object] } } }
```

How can I show all object? I want this output:

```js
>>> { data: 1, next: { data: 2, next: { data: 3, next: { data:  4, next:  null }}}}
```

Comment: Just use `JSON.stringify(object)`

Answer (score 2):

Try using console.dir().

Here is the documentation for it: https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consoledirobj-options

You will need to pass a depth value:

```
> object = { data: 1, next: { data: 2, next: { data: 3, next: { data:  4, next:  null }}}}; 
> console.dir(object,{depth:5});
{
  data: 1,
  next: { data: 2, next: { data: 3, next: { data: 4, next: null } } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to first stringify the object. You can do this by calling `console.log(JSON.stringify(object));`. It's also possible to pretty-print the object while stringifying it using `console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, 2));` (the `2` means that it will use two spaces for indentation).